# Have there been any attempts to unify statistics and decision theory into a single framework that refrains from estimating probabilities?

Tags: statistics, soft-question, decision-theory

If I understand correctly:

- statistics, narrowly construed, is all about using data to estimate probabilities.
- decision theory can then be applied to those probabilities in order to predict which decisions maximize expected utility.

I may be completely off the mark here, but I have a hunch that this is really the wrong way of going about it. Perhaps we should look for decision-theoretic methods that skip the estimation of probabilities altogether and make utility-maximizing decisions "straight from the data," so to speak. Imaginably, this could circumvent certain difficulties with the Bayesian paradigm, like finding an uninformative [prior distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability).

> **Question.** Have there been any attempts to unify statistics and decision theory into a single framework that refrains from estimating probabilities, and instead makes utility-maximizing decisions "straight from the data"?

If not, I would also be interested in answers of the form: "This probably wouldn't work because..."

Please keep it civilized, thanks.

Comment: I think a lot of statisticians would give you lengthy stares after your summary of what statistics is about. Indeed, you are off the mark! Have you read a book on decision theory before?

Comment: @ArbiasHashani, no, the extent of my knowledge is a 3rd year undergraduate course in statistical inference, and a lot of wikipedia perusing. Your comment about lengthy stares made me lol. Feel free to write an answer about why this isn't how you view statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One basic distinction in decision theory maps onto something roughly like the distinction you have in mind.

*Objective* decision theory (e.g. von Neumann & Morgenstern) addresses problems in which probabilities are already assumed to be known (maybe from statistical information), and then tries to advise or describe decision makers facing such problems.

*Subjective* decision theory (e.g. Savage) addresses problems in which probabilities are unknown, and the way it tries to describe or advise decision makers typically involves recovering implicit probabilities from "the data", where that is usually taken to be the preferences or the actions of the decision makers.